# Firefox - VideoDownloader App + Companion application not working (Ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: firefox, restricted-access

To install the browser firefox on my system I used `sudo snap install firefox`. Afterwards, I installed the extension VideoDownloader, which was working fine. But by using this extension the first time I got the message *Companion application required* and a button to install this external application. Therefore, I did the requested installation, successfully. I started a second try to download a video. But the same message *Companion application required* appears.

After some investigation I found the root cause for this. The snap-file for firefox by self is the problem. Inside of file snapcraft.yaml the option of confinement is *strict*. Therefore firefox can't reached the  *Companion application*, because the installed *Companion application* is outside of the sandbox. And by security ruleset *confinement:strict*, firefox has no permission to use the *Companion application*.

Question: How can I do a change of security ruleset *confinement:strict* into security ruleset *confinement:classic*?

Answer (score 3):

You can install Firefox by `sudo snap install firefox --classic` to do this. I'm not sure if you can convert an already existing install from strict to classic though.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but your solution is not working based on security problems. If a snap-packages has `confinement:strict `  you're not allowed to change the security option into classic. This is the reason of my question.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use `snap` or `apt` to install Firefox!**

Instead, directly download the installer from the [official website](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/), and install it by the instruction `Install Firefox from Mozilla builds (For advanced users)` from : [Install Firefox on Linux](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux).

The VideoDownloader then works.

Comment: "The VideoDownloader then works." It works only if FF is launched from within the user's folders under /home. If the FF executables are moved to /opt or anywhere outside /home/[this-user] then VideoDownloader 1. can't find net.downloadhelper.coapp and 2. DOES NOT GIVE THE OPTION to download directly through the browser. It seems to be some permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the VDH supplement app working.
The path was simple: I followed the instructions provided by VDH on the page with the download of the supplementary app, however I didn't install the .deb version (I didn't know how to start it) but the tar.gz "version".

Basically I followed the download instructions on different linux distributions, the two command lines you find on the site do all the rest.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1458955/1680832